# Cannot resolve error "default_web_client_id" in firebase auth with google and facebook

Tags: firebase, google-api, sha1

I have a project that uses firebase auth with google and facebook, and it worked fine until some weeks, in which the ide sent me this error

> Cannot resolve symbol default_web_client_id

I don't know how to solve it because in my firebase console, the sha-1 key that I generated and added when I created the project has disappeared and does not allow me to add the key again showing me this message

[Mensaje de error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SnaMf.png)

I followed the instructions on the help site and check my list of credentials in the google api console

[Lista de credenciales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cf7h8.png)

and i don't know what's the issue with firebase to add my sha-1 key

Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to download the `google-services.json` from your Firebase project. If you haven't added already your Android app to the project you can do so as described here https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup.
2. If you've already done that, just go ahead and re-download the `google-services.json`, it could have been changed. This helped me.
3. Make sure that the SHA fingerprint is filled in the Firebase Project's Android app section.